# Why do I have error in the expression editor when I sum BigDecimal in Jaspersoft Studio?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to sum two `BigDecimal`, but before to do that I need to know that this values are not null (I could made this check Java side, but I want to try Jasper side).

So, I do this check:

```
($F{a} != null ? $F{a} : new BigDecimal(0))
($F{b} != null ? $F{b} : new BigDecimal(0))
```

Now, I have to sum `a` and `b`, but if I do:

```
($F{a} != null ? $F{a} : new BigDecimal(0)).add($F{b} != null ? $F{b} : new BigDecimal(0))
```

I get:

> The current expression is not valid. Please verify it!

How can I solve?

Comment: Are **a** and **b** declared `BigDecimal`?

Comment: Consider to accept an answer on this question, if still not open.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your fields are both of class `java.math.BigDecimal` and that you are using `language="java"` or `language="groovy"`

There is **nothing wrong** with your expression!

Don't worry about the **Expression Editor** it simple can not understand that `($F{a} != null ? $F{a} : new BigDecimal(0))` is a `java.math.BigDecimal`, that is why it states *"The current expression is not valid. Please verify it!"* and show's a red dot at **.add**.

Just press **"OK"** and enjoy your result!

If you like to simplify your expression's or just remove the error in the expression editor, you can use variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Explicitly casting a new BigDecimal eliminates the exception.  Use

```
new Bigdecimal($F{a} != null ? $F{a} : new BigDecimal(0))
```

and there should be no problem.

I was wrong.  The cast eliminated Jaspers' compile time exception but in runtime it threw 'The constructor BigDecimal(NumberComparable) is undefined.'  Note the compile time exception is bad since their approach is to check each keystroke and throw up a warning as you type.  In order to complete typing the conditional, it takes double the effort in warnings closing.  Now I need my code to work without the cast and I'm about to try

```
($F{denominator} == 0 ? 0 : $F{numerator} / $F{denominator})
```